# Not redirecting to next page after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller, forms-authentication

`<authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization>`

I kept the above code snippet in web.config file after authentication and the problem started I am entering the correct credentials but still I am not redirecting to next page after successful login 
and my new url is being appended with some query string values
this is my login url:
`http://localhost:49841/LMIT/Login`
After submitting the login form with correct credentials, instead of redirecting to next page, it still stays on the same page with `http://localhost:49841/LMIT/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fLMIT%2fIndex` in the url

Comment: You need to provide code for your Login action method

Comment: [AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(Users user){
Users DbData = (from s in db.Users where s.UserName ==user.UserName select s).First();
            if (DbData != null)
            { if (user.UserName == DbData.UserName && user.Password == DbData.Password)
                {
                    
                        return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("/Index") });
                   
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return View();
        }

Comment: as i am using ajax and json thats y i used returnm json

Comment: It is best to update the question with the added code. It is much easier to see that way.

Comment: Also, you can return Json, that is not a problem but you also need to set a cookie that will tell ASP.NET that the user is authenticated.

Comment: var userCookie = new HttpCookie("user", DbData.UserId + DbData.UserName);
                userCookie.Expires.AddDays(7);  
                HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(userCookie);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try the following code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(Users user)
{
    Users DbData = (from s in db.Users where s.UserName == user.UserName select s).First();
    if (DbData != null)
    {
        if (user.UserName == DbData.UserName && user.Password == DbData.Password)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id.ToString(), true);
            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("/Index") });
        }
    } 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: i dont have problem with routing if i dont use Authorize if i keep authorize then only iam getting error